# std::vector of pairs not being sorted properly

Tags: c++, sorting, std, stdvector

I'm trying to sort a vector of pairs by their second value. I'm doing this in order to sort an unordered map, which I'm doing by converting the map to a vector, and then sorting the vector. For some reason, a few values in my vector are not in their right place. Here is my current sort function:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void sortMapByValue(std::unordered_map<T1, T2> &m) {
    std::vector<std::pair<T1, T2>> vec = std::vector<std::pair<T1, T2>>(m.begin(), m.end());

    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
        [](std::pair<T1, T2> a, std::pair<T1, T2> b) { return a.second < b.second; }
    );

    m = std::unordered_map<std::string, int>(vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

Here is my main function:

```
int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> mm;

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        mm["key" + std::to_string(i)] = i;
    }
    sortMapByValue<std::string, int>(mm);

    for (auto p : mm) {
        std::cout << p.first << " | " << p.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And here is my output:

```
key24 | 24
key23 | 23
key22 | 22
key21 | 21
key19 | 19
key17 | 17
key18 | 18
key15 | 15
key14 | 14
key12 | 12
key10 | 10
key25 | 25
key16 | 16
key9 | 9
key7 | 7
key20 | 20
key5 | 5
key4 | 4
key6 | 6
key3 | 3
key8 | 8
key2 | 2
key13 | 13
key1 | 1
key11 | 11
key0 | 0
```

I'm trying to sort my map because it will be storing the occurrences of a word inside of a file in descending order.

Edit: I have attempted with both a map and an unordered map, and it still has elements in the wrong place.

Comment: You want your `unordered_map` to be ordered a certain way?  Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: You assigned the sorted vector back to the unordered_map. And unordered_map is **unordered**, no matter how you operate on it.

Comment: @wtz I attempted this with both an ordered and unordered map, though each time the map still had elements in the improper places.

Comment: @Verve You cannot control the order of keys when iterating a map or an unordered_map **no matter how you operate on it**. The order of keys is determined by the underlying data structure (red-black tree for map or hash table for unordered_map).

Comment: I think the underlying question here is _"What C++ containers allow me to change the order of its elements?"_  You are choosing containers that don't allow that.

Comment: @wtz I did not know that; I thought elements were in the order that you inserted them. Thank you.

Comment: @Verve "*I thought elements were in the order that you inserted them*" - that is true for `std::vector`, but not for `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this.
Considering you are using `std::unordered_map`, as the name implies, it stores everything out of order.

`std::map` would be of little use either. It uses a binary tree as backing data structure and uses each node's key to determine the position into which it will be placed. If you replace `std::unordered_map` for it and run your program, you will see that entries are sorted in lexicographic order, as the keys in your map are `std::string`s.

Depending on what you want to do, you may implement a reverse map or deal with the vector representation when you need sorted entries.